# Hibernate hbm2ddl (ddl-auto) failing after upgrading spring boot 1.3.2 to 1.4.1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I was upgrading my spring boot from 1.3.2 to 1.4.1 and came across this issue.

```
Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`miq`.`#sql-66f_2a0`, CONSTRAINT `FK8py7anxsihgwdy7bkibosch86` FOREIGN KEY (`market_region_id`) REFERENCES `market_region` (`id`))
Query is : alter table miq.office add constraint FK8py7anxsihgwdy7bkibosch86 foreign key (market_region_id) references miq.market_region (id)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:939) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.4.6.jar!/:na]
```

In spring boot 1.3.2 it works fine. I think it has something to do with the upgradation of hibernate from 4 to 5. My application.yml is below:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: miq-batch
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scdf
    username: root
    password: root
    driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    testOnBorrow: true
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
    hikari:
      pool-name: SpringBootHikariCP
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
      database: profile      
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      show_sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: update
        cache:
          use_second_level_cache: true
          region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
          use_query_cache: true
          use_collection_cache: true
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like MariaDB prevents you from creating a foreign key constraint on `miq.office` table. This is thus a data problem. Look in table `miq.office` to see if one (or more) record(s) has an unknown `market_region_id` (i.e. that does not have a corresponding record in table `market_region`).

Why is happening when upgrading ?
I guess that when you upgrade Spring-boot, you also and upgrade MariaDB driver, and this latter one is more strict regarding foreign constraint creation.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this issue by adding:

```
hibernate:
    implicit_naming_strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl
```